# Index out of bound exception in java

Tags: java, algorithm, exception

pred[] is a char array taken as input from the user. the expected input is in form predicate(param1,param2). this while loop is to detect the start and end indices of predicate, param1, and param2 but for some reason it is giving an exception.

```
    int k =0;
    while(pred[k]!="\0"){
            System.out.println("k="+k);
            if ("(".equals(pred[k])) {
                param1_st = k + 1;
                pred1_end = k - 1;
            }
            if (",".equals(pred[k])) {
                param1_end = k - 1;
                param2_st = k + 1;
            }
            if (")".equals(pred[k])) {
                param2_end = k - 1;

            }
            k++;

        }
```

output:

```
Enter a predicate 1
abd(sd,sdf)
Entered predicate is: abd(sd,sdf)
Enter a predicate 2
abd(x,db)
Entered predicate is: 
abd(x,db)k=0
k=1
k=2
k=3
k=4
k=5
k=6
k=7
k=8
k=9
k=10
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:11
at unification.Unif.main(Unif.java:41)
```

Comment: what's \0 supposed to mean? are you checking for the end of the line?

Comment: start of while loop
while(pred[k]!="\0"){

Comment: `while(pred[k]!="\0"){` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Based on `if ("(".equals(pred[k]))` you seem to know how.

Comment: yes, i'm checking end of line

Comment: shouldn't it be n then? also can you not use the length of the array? like -> `while(k < pred.length - 1)`?

Comment: what i don't understand is that why is it giving an index out of bound exception

Comment: Because you have 10 elements in the array pred but you are doing pred[11] which doesn't exist

Comment: thanks! just realized that.

Comment: Also based on that very link you referenced it says not to use `==` to compare strings so why are you doing just that? use `!("\0".equals(pred[k])`

Comment: your while loop will go forever because your condition will never be `!(false)`

Comment: Is `pred` a char array, or a String array?  If it is actually a char array, then comparing `"\0"` is completely nonsensical -- and Java doesn't use null-terminated strings anyway.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it must be a string array but it's still nonsensical because unless `pred[x] = "\0";` was done somewhere it will not be the same object as "\0". and since it's being read in from the console it won't equal.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the while loop evaluates to a string comparison and in this case it will always return `true` value. A result is an infinite loop, since the `k` variable keeps incrementing, the index pointer will cause out-bound-exception when it goes beyond the array size limit.

```
while(pred[k]!="\0")
```

try to evaluate using length property instead.

```
while(k < pred.length )
```